# Angular2 components style driven by container defined CSS

Tags: css, angular

Let's say I have a component `MyComponent` whose view contains a table

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col1">COL1</th>
                    <th class="col2">COL2</th>
                    <th class="col3">COL3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="#item of items">
                    <td class="col1">{{item.content1}}</td>
                    <td class="col2">{{item.content2}}</td>
                    <td class="col3">{{item.content3}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I would like to MyComponent within different container (e.g. `Container1` and `Container2`) and be able to define some attributes of the table (e.g. the width of each column) using the CSS files I can attach to the containers. For instance in `Container1` I could define a CSS file like this

```
.col1 {
    width: 40%;
}
.col2 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col3 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

while in Container2 I could have a different CSS file with different attributes.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage [ngStyle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgStyle-directive.html) and [Input](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) for example:

`MyComponent` would be:

```
@Component({
  selector:'table-component',
  template:`
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th [ngStyle]="col1css">COL1</th>
          <th [ngStyle]="col2css">COL2</th>
          <th [ngStyle]="col3css">COL3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#item of items">
          <td [ngStyle]="col1css">{{item.content1}}</td>
          <td [ngStyle]="col2css">{{item.content2}}</td>
          <td [ngStyle]="col3css">{{item.content3}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>`
})
export class MyComponent{
  @Input() col1Css;
  @Input() col2Css;
  @Input() col3Css;
}
```

And then in the containers:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'container1',
    directives:[MyComponent],
    template: `<table-component [col2Css]="col2Css" [col3Css]="col3Css" [col1Css]="col1Css"></table-component>`
})
export class Container1 {
  col1Css = {'width':'40%'};
  col2Css = {'width':'30%'};
  col3Css = {'width':'30%'};
}
```

[Example in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QWWzDfwBNFB9tfW4SQNq?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you have different `.css` files, you could leverage `styleUrls` in `@Component` decorator which can accept `array` of string. Please note that you can achieve your goal many ways and it has a broad scope so its hard to say particular way. But I feel like this can help you (don't know up to which extend). In plunker I'm using different stylesheets with different attributes as you said. Your question can have many answers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RaJgtc?p=preview

```
@Component({
  ...
  styleUrls: ['src/style.css','src/styleone.css'],
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first go with @Abdulrahman's approach and if you run into situations where you need more flexibility because you don't know in advance what should be able to be styled from the outside, you can use shadow-piercing CSS combinator `>>>`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'container1-cmp',
  directives: [MyComponent],
  template: `
    <my-component></my-component>
    <my-component></my-component>
    <my-component></my-component>`,
  styles: [`
    my-component >>> .col1 { width: 40%; }
    my-component >>> .col2 { width: 30%; }
    my-component >>> .col3 { width: 30%; }
  `]
})
export class Container1Cmp {
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'container2-cmp',
  directives: [MyComponent],
  template: `
    <my-component></my-component>
    <my-component></my-component>
    <my-component></my-component>`,
  styles: [`
    my-component >>> .col1 { width: 10%; }
    my-component >>> .col2 { width: 10%; }
    my-component >>> .col3 { width: 50%; }
  `]
})
export class Container2Cmp {
}
```